# How to patch and recompile axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar in wso2esb 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, recompile

If I modify manually axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar, wso2esb 4.9.0 crashes at startup with the following message:

```
Could not start: null(reference:file:../plugins/axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar:17). It's state is uninstalled.
```

In my case, I want to apply the following patch : https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/commit/0f826cbf230b8c855b041ea1db3a751319cd3e91 that was released for wso2esb 5.0.0

Note:
This happens even if I only unzip the jar, and then recreate it as it with

```
$ jar cf *
```

How can I patch and recompile axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar in wso2esb 4.9.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically follow the below steps. But before that check if the same fix was issued using a WUM update. If not

1. You need to download the relevant tag first [v1.6.1-wso2v14](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/tree/v1.6.1-wso2v14)
2. Cherry-pick the commit that you wanna include. (This may be straightforward in some cases, but there might be issues in some scenarios since there can be a lot of changes or dependency classes been changed. So be careful on that)
3. Build the tag with the fix
4. Get the build axis2_1.6.1-wso2v14.jar
5. Create a new patch directory with a higher number inside `<ESB-Home>/repository/component/patches directory`
6. Copy the jar file to that directory e.g. patch1000/axis2_1.6.1-wso2v14.jar (Check the jar file name, it should be same as in plugins directory)
7. Restart the server

You can refer to [Doc1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process), [Doc2](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso-2-easy-patching-wso2-products) for more info

Edited
Don't try to package it using jar cf command. Run mvn clean install. This is not a standard jar but an OSGi bundle. So copy the jar file you get from mvn clean install. If the name differs just rename the jar name (- to _)

Comment: I tried the following and it didn't work:

    git checkout v1.6.1-wso2v14

    apply patch to source

    mvn compile

    unzip previous axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar

    replace the single modified class file

    jar cf * axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar

    mkdir wso2esb/repository/components/patches/patch1000

    cp axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar wso2esb/repository/components/patches/patch1000
    bin/wso2server.sh

Comment: got the following error

[2018-07-25 11:22:46,814]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.PatchInstaller} -  Patch changes detected 
[2018-07-25 11:22:47,115]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Backed up plugins to patch0000
[2018-07-25 11:22:47,162]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Patch verification started
[2018-07-25 11:22:47,211]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Patch verification successfully completed.
Could not start: null(reference:file:../plugins/axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar:17). It's state is uninstalled.

Comment: I did the unzip and rezip operation because when I run mvn package on the source, I get a jar with classes missing. The jar name is also somewhat different: axis2-1.6.1-wso2v14.jar (patched) vs axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14.jar (originally shipped by wso2 4.9.0)

Comment: But the classes inside the jars are totally different. The distributed jar from the release doesn't seem to have been build with mvn clean install on the https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/tree/v1.6.1-wso2v14 tag

Comment: You need to get the built jar file from https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/tree/v1.6.1-wso2v14/orbit/axis2 directory :)